# Getting the textual content of an HTML tag using JQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML (I omitted the JQuery import):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span class="element_to_read">Ciao</span> <br/>
    <span class="element_to_read">Hello</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

And have the following JavaScript running:

```
console.log($(".element_to_read"));
```

Which correctly returns `[span.element_to_read, span.element_to_read]`. I tried executing the `.text()`, `.html()`, `.value` (by accessing `$(".element_to_read")[index]) over the elements contained in the list, but apparently there is no way I can get the content (textual values) of the selected elements (that would be Ciao and Hello).

How can I do this? Thanks

EDIT: As always, people over here is *not* able to read an entire question top to bottom. "I tried executing the `.text()`, `.html()`, `.value` over the elements..." means I know how to iterate through an array, but I do not know how to read the values (Ciao, Hello) in the elements selected (the two `span` classes).

EDIT2: Thanks for all the downvotes. Apparently questions that are too easy should be hidden.

Comment: You need to iterate it, because its returning an `array` of values.

Comment: When do you want to get the innerText? Add complete JS code

Comment: Why do you think `.text()` doesn't work?

Comment: @Vohuman Depends on how it is used

Comment: have you seen my FIDDLE?

Comment: @Tushar  In this case it should return the text contents of those 2 selected elements. I have asked that question for clarification.

Comment: For your **EDIT**_I tried executing the .text(), .html(), .value over the elements..._ really? where is that code? at your system....! can't see your system here in your question?

Comment: @Jai Who knows jQuery knows what I am doing wrong. There is no point in specifying the output (`VM1409:70 Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].html() is not a function`) for each of the functions I tried to run.

Comment: @Masiar, you edited your question later. Well, during iteration you can either create an array or another string to read combined values.

Comment: @Masiar That is why code is needed to be in the question. See `$(...)[0].html()` As you are trying to add index `[0]` to the jQuery object which converts it to DOM element and DOM elements don't have jQuery methods.

Comment: @ParkashKumar It should be `$(".element_to_read").eq(0).text();`. `get(index)` works like the bracket notation version: `[index]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will require to iterate over result returned by similar `class` selector as it will return `array` of values.

Then, If you just want to get text values, use `.text()` as following:

```
$(".element_to_read").each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8noqsod1/)

Or if you want to get text value with nested tags use `.html()`, as following:

```
$(".element_to_read").each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6gw46f62/1/)

While, during iteration you can either create an `array` or another `string` to read combined values as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/2s4wmocd/)**

This might work as shown in FIDDLE.

```
console.log($("span").text());
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/2s4wmocd/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var info=[];
    $("span").each(function(){
        info.push($(this).text());

    });
    console.log(info);
});
```

Comment: Nice one, but I need to have them as separate values. Having them in an array is cool, but I needed something like `$("span")[0].text()` (in your example) which cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()`

```
$(".element_to_read").each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

To fetch innerText.

Answer (score 1):

Try like following. This should work fine.

```js
var text=[];
$('.element_to_read').each(function(){
    text.push($(this).text());
})
alert(text.join());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="element_to_read">Ciao</span> <br/>
<span class="element_to_read">Hello</span>
```